# Iterating through a javascript object and outputting certain information based upon criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, iteration

I have an array of objects which i'd like to get values from:

```
    lastChanceSeats: Object
      assignedSeats: Array[6]
        0: Object
          SeatId: "29A"
          passengerName: "Mr test1 test1"
          sectorSequence: 1
        1: Object
          SeatId: "22A"
          passengerName: "Mr test1 test1"
          sectorSequence: 2
        2: Object
          SeatId: "29B"
          passengerName: "Mrs test2 test2"
          sectorSequence: 1
        3: Object
          SeatId: "22B"
          passengerName: "Mrs test2 test2"
          sectorSequence: 2
        4: Object
          SeatId: "29C"
          passengerName: "Master test3 test3"
          sectorSequence: 1
        5: Object
          SeatId: "22C"
          passengerName: "Master test3 test3"
          sectorSequence: 2
```

I'd like to present the data in the following format:

- First {passengerName}
- {sectorSequence: 1} + {SeatId}
- {sectorSequence: 2} + {SeatId}

...then the same for passenger two, three and so on.

Comment: you should use `html` to achieve that.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm after how id iterate through the array to pull the data in the way presented.

Answer (score 1):

use a simple template and loop though each item to generate your output:

```
var data=[
    {
        "SeatId": "29A",
        "passengerName": "Mr test1 test1",
        "sectorSequence": 1
    },
    {
        "SeatId": "22A",
        "passengerName": "Mr test1 test1",
        "sectorSequence": 2
    },
    {
        "SeatId": "29B",
        "passengerName": "Mrs test2 test2",
        "sectorSequence": 1
    }
]


function template(ob, str){
   return str.replace(/{([\w\s.\$]+?)}/g, 
     function(j,a){  return ob[a]||"";  } );
}

strTemplate="First {passengerName}  {sectorSequence} + {SeatId}";

out=$(data).map(function(i,item){ return template(item, strTemplate)}).toArray().join("\n");

alert(out);

/* result:
First Mr test1 test1  1 + 29A
First Mr test1 test1  2 + 22A
First Mrs test2 test2  1 + 29B  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordered iteration over object properties is not possible.

You could do something like this:

```
var data=[
    {
        "SeatId": "29A",
        "passengerName": "Mr test1 test1",
        "sectorSequence": 1
    },
    {
        "SeatId": "22A",
        "passengerName": "Mr test1 test1",
        "sectorSequence": 2
    },
    {
        "SeatId": "29B",
        "passengerName": "Mrs test2 test2",
        "sectorSequence": 1
    }
], 
orderedObjectProps = ['SeatId', 'passengerName', 'sectorSequence'],
dataLength = data.length,
propsLength = orderedObjectProps.length,
i = 0;

for(i; i < dataLength; i++) {
  var obj = data[i],
  j = 0;
  for(j; j < propsLength; j++) {
    var propName = orderedObjectProps[j],
    propValue = obj[propName];
    console.log(propValue);
  }
}
```

The above code will print the values in the order that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the above however I'm trying to get the first passenger name and list their given seat numbers underneath, then the second passenger name and their seat numbers, etc, rather than reordering the properties. I need to look at each object, evaluate whether the name is the same in any of them and list the applicable seats underneath... does that make sense?!?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same data that in the answer above you could try this snippet

```js
var data=[
    {
        "SeatId": "29A",
        "passengerName": "Mr test1 test1",
        "sectorSequence": 1
    },
    {
        "SeatId": "22A",
        "passengerName": "Mr test1 test1",
        "sectorSequence": 2
    },
    {
        "SeatId": "29B",
        "passengerName": "Mrs test2 test2",
        "sectorSequence": 1
    }
]

function test_iteration(data) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    console.log(`SeatId : ${e.SeatId}`);
    console.log(`passengerName : ${e.passengerName}`);
    console.log(`sectorSequence : ${e.sectorSequence}`);
  })
}
function test_iteration_2(data) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    for (var prop in e) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, prop)) {
        console.log(`${prop} : ${e[prop]}`);
      }
    }
  })
}

test_iteration_2(data) ;
```